# Network names switch on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspbian

I'm Running multiple `Raspberry Pi` 3's with Raspbian jessie.
There is a wifi interface on board, and I added another wifi USB dongle. On all devices, these defaulted to `wlan0` and `wlan1` respectively.

After installing some tool on one of the devices (using apt-get) the names switched, so now the USB dongle became `wlan0` and the on-board wifi became `wlan1`.

I understand that I could not rely on these names to be the same everywhere, but I need to make some assumptions, as the USB dongle has different capabilities than the on-board card. H**ow could I `programmatically` make my code target the right device each time?**

If I have an SD card with a running environment, am I guaranteed to get the same network names if I plug the SD into another (identical) set of hardware? (evidence suggests otherwise)..

Can I run some script to assign the names the way I want (based on the hardware differences) so I can run the software predictably?

Can I switch the names back after they changed?

Please provide Raspbian specific commands. I have been trying random Linux/Ubuntu advice which didn't work or worse :(

Comment: It's a `udev` rule. The tool you installed may have removed the original rule and installed a new rule. All you have to do is recreate the rule. There's no specific command to change it. It's a text file that you can modify with your favorite editor.

Comment: use the MAC address https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2013/01/11/how-to-change-the-mac-address-of-an-ethernet-interface/

Answer (score 2):

You can assign device names by using `udev` and defining you own rules.  Please see [debianhelp udev](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/udev.htm) for an detailes description of how to do that.

Check the script`/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`, which records and reserves interface names for future use.

You can also write a new udev rule to give your devices fixed names, based on the mac address. To do this add a file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` called `10-network-device.rules` with smething like that: `SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="12:34:56:78:9a:bc", NAME="myusbwifi"`.

Finally this [forum article](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=55527) may help.

Comment: How would the rule look if I want to base it on the hardware type/model, and how would I find the right value to provide for a specific wireless adapter?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you request "programmatically make my code target the right device each time", I suggest you to activate **predictable network names**:

```
# raspi-config
```

Then choose:

```
2  --> Network Options
N3 --> Enable/Disable predictable network
```

After rebooting the network device names will include the MAC Address, like:

```
$ ifconfig
enxb827ebff1dd5: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.111.13  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.11.255
        inet6 fe80::d4b:5c22:8c71:3470  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:ff:1d:d5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 12260  bytes 12573583 (11.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8150  bytes 743690 (726.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

You can even predict the name based on the MAC Address of each card, like in `enxb827ebff1dd5` for `b8:27:eb:ff:1d:d5`.