# Predictable Network Interface Names inconsistently applied in Stretch

Tags: networking, wifi, raspbian-stretch

I have a PI 3 B running Stretch, and I have enabled Predictable Network Interface Names, using `raspi-config`. However, the naming is not being consistently applied. The results of `ifconfig` are

```
enxb827eb690477: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:69:04:77  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 9  bytes 524 (524.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9  bytes 524 (524.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.7  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe3c:5122  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:3c:51:22  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4235  bytes 239735 (234.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 38  bytes 5507 (5.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx74da38de4952: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.107  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::8886:5544:cb29:2c2c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 74:da:38:de:49:52  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8087  bytes 1169992 (1.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 69  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 12121  bytes 1311005 (1.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

- enxb827eb690477 is the onboard ethernet interface
- wlx74da38de4952 is the onboard WiFi interface
- wlan1 is an EDIMax N150 USB WiFi dongle

Why are 2 of the interfaces getting the new names, while the 3rd interface is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will find wlx74da38de4952  is **NOT** the onboard WiFi interface.

Network interfaces have names formed from a prefix en — Ethernet or wl — wlan followed by x indicating MAC and the MAC e.g. enxb827eb123456 or wlx00c140123456. The onboard WiFi of the Pi3 and PIZeroW which is connected over **sdio** will however use the name wlan0. See [predictable network interface names](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/amd64/release-notes/ch-whats-new.en.html#new-interface-names)

Your `wlan1` has a MAC in the range used by the Foundation.

You can verify with `sudo iw dev wlx74da38de4952 info` and `sudo iw dev wlan0 info`

I must admit I do not know why `wlan1` would be used, but the naming process allocates names in the order interfaces are found, and has always been unpredictable.

Comment: You are correct, I had it backwards. So, if I understand correctly, sdio interfaces simply get indexed (e.g., wlan0, wlan1), things stuck in slots get a bus/slot number derived name (e.g., wlp3s0), and USB interfaces get a MAC derived name (e.g., wwx028037ec0200).

Answer (score 3):

According to [Raspberry Pi Forums: RPi3 wlan0 doesn't change with predictable names](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1219792#p1219792):

> On the Pi only USB devices (like the ehternet adapter) use the predictable names
> The wifi adapter uses SDIO and apparently there's no mechanism for predictable names using that channel.

So predictible interface names will never work with the onboard wifi device.

However, you can hardcode an interface name by creating a file at `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-network-device.rules` with this line:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx", NAME="wlanX"
```

Replacing `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` with your device's **lowercase** mac address (found with `ip link`) and `wlanX` with whatever name you choose.  (It doesn't have to start with `wlan`.)

source: [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange: Network names switch on Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/51369/90037)