# renaming network interface

Tags: networking

I have a number of raspberry pi 3 and 4 on my network and I would like to standardize much of the networking for all of the units, as well as the linux host PC's.  Is there any reason I can't change the ethernet interface name in the conf files.  Right now I have a range of names from eth0 to enp9s2.  All have unique mac addresses as per standard, but the interface names are basically random and I would like to set up a standard networking.  I can programatically change the mac address in the interfaces and would like to link that to a standard interface name such as eth0 or eth1.

Comment: The normative way to do this is to use udev rules, but you might want to have a look at this first: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/80439/5538 ...I do not know if that is still available or if it works as described.

Comment: What OS are you using? "enp9s2" has NOTHING to do with the Pi. This is based on physical/geographical location of the connector of the hardware.

Comment: using Raspbian Jessie and Buster and this is what Raspbian has named the broadcom ethernet interface, clearly this is only one instance but the naming of the ethernet interface is done by the OS at first boot.  The only software running other than Raspbian is Oracle Java and it is loaded after first boot.